# How to get cabal and nix work together

Tags: haskell, cabal, nix

As far as I understood, **Nix** is alternative for **cabal sandbox**.
I finally managed to install Nix, but I still don't understand how it can replace a sandbox.

I understand you don't need cabal using Nix and the wrapped version of GHC; however if you want
to publish a package you'll need at some point to package it using cabal. Therefore, you need to be able to write and test your cabal configuration within NIX. How do you do that?

Ideally, I would like an environment similar to cabal sandbox but "contained" within NIX, is that possible? In fact, what I really would like is the equivalent of nested sandboxes — as I usually work on projects made of multiple packages.

## Update about my current workflow

At the moment I work on 2 or 3 independent projects (P1, P2, P3) which are each composed of 2 or 3 cabal modules/packages, let's say for P1: L11, L12 (libraries)
 and E11 (executables). E11 depends on L12 which depends on L11. I mainly split the executables from the library because they are private and kept on a private git repo.

In theory, each project could have this own sandbox (shared between its submodules). I tried that (having a common sandbox for L11 L12 and E11), but it's quickly annoying because, if you modify L11, you can't rebuild it because E11 depends on it, so I have to uninstall E11 first to recompile L11.
It might be no exactly the case, but I encounter the similar problem.
This would be fine if I were occasionally modifying L11, but in practice, I changed it more that E11.

As the shared sandbox doesn't work, so I went back to the one sandbox for every package solution. It's working but is less than ideal. 
The main problem is if I modify L11, I need to compile it twice (once in L11, and then again in E11). Also, each time I'm starting a new sandbox, as everybody knows, I need to wait a while to get everything package downloaded and recompiled.

So by using Nix, I'm hopping to be able to set up separate cabal "environments" per project, which solves all the issue aboves.

Hope this is clearer.

Comment: This might help: https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2014-02-04-how-i-develop-with-nixos.html

Comment: I've read it many times, but I haven't be able to extract the needed information.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I do all my development using Nix and cabal these days, and I can happily say that they work in harmony very well. My current workflow is very new, in that it relies on features in `nixpkgs` that have only just reached the master branch. As such, the first thing you'll need to do is clone `nixpkgs` from Github:

```sh
cd ~
git clone git://github.com/nixos/nixpkgs
```

(In the future this won't be necessary, but right now it is).

### Single Project Usage

Now that we have a `nixpkgs` clone, we can start using the *`haskellng`* package set. `haskellng` is a rewrite of how we package things in Nix, and is of interest to us for being more predictable (package names match Hackage package names) and more configurable. First, we'll install the `cabal2nix` tool, which can automate some things for us, and we'll also install `cabal-install` to provide the `cabal` executable:

```sh
nix-env -f ~/nixpkgs -i -A haskellngPackages.cabal2nix -A haskellngPackages.cabal-install
```

From this point, it's all pretty much clear sailing.

If you're starting a new project, you can just call `cabal init` in a new directory, as you would normally. When you're ready to build, you can turn this `.cabal` file into a development environment:

```sh
cabal init
# answer the questions
cabal2nix --shell my-project.cabal > shell.nix
```

This gives you a `shell.nix` file, which can be used with `nix-shell`. You don't need to use this very often though - the only time you'll usually use it is with `cabal configure`:

```sh
nix-shell -I ~ --command 'cabal configure'
```

`cabal configure` caches absolute paths to everything, so now when you want to build you just use `cabal build` as normal:

```sh
cabal build
```

Whenever your `.cabal` file changes you'll need to regenerate `shell.nix` - just run the command above, and then `cabal configure` afterwards.

### Multiple Project Usage

The approach scales nicely to multiple projects, but it requires a little bit more manual work to "glue" everything together. To demonstrate how this works, lets consider my [`socket-io`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/socket-io) library. This library depends on [`engine-io`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/engine-io), and I usually develop both at the same time.

The first step to Nix-ifying this project is to generate `default.nix` expressions along side each individual `.cabal` file:

```sh
cabal2nix engine-io/engine-io.cabal > engine-io/default.nix
cabal2nix socket-io/socket-io.cabal > socket-io/default.nix
```

These `default.nix` expressions are functions, so we can't do much right now. To call the functions, we write our own `shell.nix` file that explains how to combine everything. For `engine-io/shell.nix`, we don't have to do anything particularly clever:

```
with (import <nixpkgs> {}).pkgs;
(haskellngPackages.callPackage ./. {}).env
```

For `socket-io`, we need to depend on `engine-io`:

```
with (import <nixpkgs> {}).pkgs;
let modifiedHaskellPackages = haskellngPackages.override {
      overrides = self: super: {
        engine-io = self.callPackage ../engine-io {};
        socket-io = self.callPackage ./. {};
      };
    };
in modifiedHaskellPackages.socket-io.env
```

Now we have `shell.nix` in each environment, so we can use `cabal configure` as before.

The key observation here is that whenever `engine-io` changes, we need to reconfigure `socket-io` to detect these changes. This is as simple as running

```sh
cd socket-io; nix-shell -I ~ --command 'cabal configure'
```

Nix will notice that `../engine-io` has changed, and rebuild it before running `cabal configure`.

Comment: Thank you! This looks much simpler than what I'm doing at the moment. Can you expand a bit on what haskellng is doing ("how we package things in nix")? Is the workflow for cross-project dependencies similar to what you described in https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2014-02-04-how-i-develop-with-nixos.html, or has that changed?

Comment: `nix-env -f ~/nixpkgs -i -A haskellngPackages.cabal2nix -A haskellngPackages.cabal` returns:
`error: attribute ‘cabal’ in selection path ‘haskellngPackages.cabal’ not found` for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: In my experience, working from HEAD nixpkgs is painful in a compile-the-world sense.  Maybe suggest checking out a recent channel version (am I getting the terminology right)?

Comment: @KrisNuttycombe I think Ollie meant `haskellngPackages.cabal-install`.

Comment: cabal2nix-2.0 seems to have some problems building... "Setup: At least the following dependencies are missing:
QuickCheck -any, deepseq-generics -any, hspec -any" and yet all three of those packages appear to install fine from haskellngPackages... @ocharles any suggestions?

Comment: @ocharles That's pretty much what I'm looking for. Seems much simpler that your original blog post. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @ocharles I updated my question to explain my workflow.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated my answer. @KrisNuttycombe, I think this is what you're looking for too. Re problems installing `cabal2nix` - best line there is to discuss this on the Nixpkgs Github issue tracker.

Comment: @KrisNuttycombe Got the same error yesterday, but after a `git pull` today I can install the most recent `cabal2nix` just fine.

Comment: This command (`cabal2nix --shell my-project.cabal > shell.nix`) doesn't work for me. Instead I had to use `cabal2nix --shell ./. > shell.nix` and edit the `src` attribute to point to `./src`.

Comment: @ocharles I tried it with toy projects and it seems to be indeed exactly what I'm looking for. However things were not as straight forward but I understand it's a work in progress, and the issues are out of topic on SO.

Comment: @ocharles I noticed that cabal-install is not part of the environment create by shell.nix. Do you have it installed globally? Is it just the one provided by nix-env -i cabal-install? I sort of liked having it as part of the shell environment and not having to have ghc or anything else installed globally

Comment: @purefn it is installed globally, as mentioned above.

Comment: _"in the future"_ — so are we now in the future yet or not? :)

Comment: Also, as of 23 Dec '15, how does Cabal+Nix compare to Stack and/or Stack+Nix?

Comment: @ErikAllik We're "in the future" in that haskellng is now just the standard way of packaging haskell stuff in nixpkgs (took me a while to figure that out when I recently jumped to nixos; there's so many tutorials telling you to use haskellng). I tried stack+nix, since I was using stack without nix and it has some integration, but have so far concluded I prefer cabal+nix; nix itself provides the sandboxing, lts package sets, and ability to depend on non-haskell projects, and I'm finding it easier to just work with nix-shell than to mix in stack exec as well.

Comment: @ErikAllik Relevant links about Stack+Nix: http://www.tweag.io/blog/stack-nix-portable-reproducible-builds and https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/doc/nix_integration.md